# Creating multiple relationships between objects

Tags: iphone, core-data, ipad

I have a core data model with 2 entities: Collection and Image. There's a one to many relationship between Colletion and Image, reflected by an 'images' accessor on the Collection side and a 'collection' accessor on the Image side.

There's an additional relationship called keyImage, which is a 1:1 relationship between Collection and Image. One of the images in the collection is the key image and I've modeled that by creating an additional 1:1 relationship. This one has an accessor called keyImage in Collection and isKeyImageFor in Image.

I can work with this model mostly fine, there is however one thing that doesn't work.

```
// Add an image as the key image.
coll.keyImage = keyImage;

// Add the image to the collection
[coll addImagesObject:keyImage];
```

Both of these lines work independently. However, if I do both (the image should both be in the collection and assigned as the keyImage) then keyImage ends up being null after saving the data. It's as if the 1:N relationship nullifies the 1:1 relationship, even though they use separate keys and accessors.

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: how does the source files look like? have you written code on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can make Core Data do this. You've created two contradictory relationships.

Maybe add a property 'isKeyImage', to the Image entity, and then you'd be able to pull out the single image with that property set.

Or, keep the key image separate from Images. Unfortunately I think you'd need a separate KeyImage entity defined in Core Data, with it's own relationship from Collection. I'd be happy to learn that you can make multiple links between the same entities.

Answer (score 0):

"keyImage" variable name collision?

coll.keyImage = keyImageObject;

[coll addImagesObject:keyImageObject];